# laravel eloquent groupBy takes too much times to fetch

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent

I'm implementing an API from my laravel database. 
the database includes more than 300000+ data this is my API  query 
when I try this query it takes 1230ms

```
       $products = \App\items::with([
        'item_store' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('size', 'item_id');
        },

        'pics' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('img_url', 'item_id');
        },

        'brand' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('item_id', 'brand_id');
        },
        'brand.brand' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('brand_id', 'brand_name');
        }

    ])
    ->select('item_id', 'short_name', 'price', 'price_old')
    ->orderBy('Price', 'Asc')
     ->whereIn('category_id', $arr)
    ->paginate(32);
```

but when I add groupBy its takes 13s seconds to load what is the issue?? how can I resolve this?

after adding groupBy

```
        $products = \App\items::with([
        'item_store' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('size', 'item_id');
        },

        'pics' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('img_url', 'item_id');
        },

        'brand' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('item_id', 'brand_id');
        },
        'brand.brand' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('brand_id', 'brand_name');
        }

    ])
    ->select('item_id', 'short_name', 'price', 'price_old')
    ->orderBy('Price', 'Asc')
      ->groupBy('Sku')
     ->whereIn('category_id', $arr)
    ->paginate(32);
```

Comment: where is this `groupBy` being called?

Comment: At the api call

Comment: try using querybuilder instead of eloquent. maybe that will fix the issue.